# AVPlayerItem's canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused doesn't have any effect

Tags: avplayer, http-live-streaming, avplayeritem

Since iOS 9 / tvOS 9 AVPlayerItem instances have the new Boolean variable `canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused`.

The documentation states:

"Indicates whether the player item can use network resources to keep playback state up to date while paused
For live streaming content, the player item may need to use extra networking and power resources to keep playback state up to date when paused. **For example, when this property is set to YES, the seekableTimeRanges property will be periodically updated to reflect the current state of the live stream.**"

I have been testing this property on apple TV and observed the seekableTimeRanges whilst the live video stream is paused, but it doesn't appear to matter whether I set it to yes/no -- the time range contained in seekableTimeRanges updates periodically in both cases.

Are you getting similar results?

Comment: I have similar problem. I set canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused to false but still see network activity (buffering) after i call pause() and i put  my app into background. Is it a bug?

Comment: I recently experienced the same problem, but on phone instead of an apple TV. Have you found a solution in the meantime?